# Get access to value of command to run in zsh (value of -c paramter)

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

TLDR: How to I get access to the value of the command passed in via `zsh -c "command"` before the command is executed. Assuming this code is going to run in either `~/.zshenv` (or `~/.zshrc` if `zsh` is invoked as a login shell).

---

I'm running on a machine where I'm unable to run `chsh` and have the value persist. To work around that I have the following in my `~/.zshrc`.

```bash
local nix_zsh_exe="path to my own installation of zsh"
if [[ -z "$ZSH_AUTO_RAN_NIX_ZSH" && -x ''${nix_zsh_exe} ]]; then
  export ZSH_AUTO_RAN_NIX_ZSH=true
  export SHELL=''${nix_zsh_exe}
  exec $SHELL --login
fi
```

This broke IntelliJ/Pycharm and the like's ability to get the environment variables on a mac. IntelliJ executes the following command in a subprocess and parses the output to get the environment variables that a *normal* (i.e. interactive login) shell would have had.

```bash
$SHELL -l -i -c '${PATH_TO_INTELLIJ_APP_DIR}/bin/printenv
```

I know I find if it's a login or interactive shell by looking at `setopt -o` or via the `$options` array. I thus need a way to get access to the command passed it so I can re-exec the other zsh install with the original parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`$ZSH_EXECUTION_STRING`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Parameters-Set-By-The-Shell) parameter to get the value set by using `zsh -c`.

> `ZSH_EXECUTION_STRING`:
> If the shell was started with the option -c, this contains the argument passed to the option. Otherwise it is not set.

Here's what it looks like in the terminal:

```
$ echo $ZSH_EXECUTION_STRING

$ echo $ZSH_SCRIPT

$ ./scr.zsh
$ZSH_SCRIPT: ./scr.zsh
$ZSH_EXECUTION_STRING:

$ zsh -itc 'echo "$ZSH_EXECUTION_STRING" && ./scr.zsh'
echo "$ZSH_EXECUTION_STRING" && ./scr.zsh
$ZSH_SCRIPT: ./scr.zsh
$ZSH_EXECUTION_STRING:
```

This may also be useful for autolaunching other interactive terminal programs  like tmux. Here's [an example](https://github.com/romkatv/zsh-bench/blob/3bdd47bece687ec532f19f79c4e4b996e22b2226/configs/zcomet/skel/.zshrc#L1-L3) snippet which launches `tmux` on launch when placed in your zshrc:

```bash
if [[ -z ${TMUX+X}${ZSH_SCRIPT+X}${ZSH_EXECUTION_STRING+X} ]]; then
  exec tmux
fi
```